# Change the background in the browser without affecting the rest

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking to build my first extension that will change the background of the image in the browser
my extension should create a new tab page after that it should change the background on the new page

but the problem is that after changing the background, all other options also disappear

that’s what my new page looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myClu.jpg)

here is what it looks like after launching my extension there is just a picture everything else is gone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3m6d.jpg)

so my final question is can i make these background changes without affecting the search bar and other gadgets?

Comment: How are you changing it? Add a [mre].

Comment: Extensions can't do that. Only [themes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes) can do that. Extensions can [override the entire `newtab` page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) so you can implement it the way you want from scratch yourself.